# data structure for Time and memory constraint

Tags: java

What is the best approach to store and search for the primitive data types? Data structure that can tackle both time constraint and memory constraint? websites/books from where I can get clear knowledge on these things?

Comment: Can you be more specific? e.g. are you looking for data structures that would store a set of `int` for searching purposes with fast search in least memory?

Comment: Yeah Sabir Khan. In HackerEarth, code developed by me is taking a lot of time to run,  it's going beyond the specified time and memory constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Try this book

> Data Structures and Algorithms in Java By Adam Drozdek Second Edition

It helped me a lot and it helps in **memory management**,**data compression** and helps in a deep knowledge of data structures and algorithms.

To get memory constraint as a thing in data structures,stop using **dynamic memory allocation**(Dynamic Programming) cause it saves memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ready to sacrifice the flexibility around **adding an element** and  **deleting an element** from your data structure then a sorted `int[]` is the best bet you got as far as memory efficiency is concerned.

Since array is sorted, you can perform binary search.

if your initial load of this array is going to be few million ints and later there is a chance to add few hundred ints only, you can supplement `int[]` with another data structure like `ArrayList` to temporary hold those additions and then merge `ArrayList` to `int[]` once size grows significantly.

Deletion can be handled by setting that element with some fairly small unused negative number but yes that would not be a very clean solution. Or you can handle deletion again by a supplementary data structure if deletion is rare.

Its all trade - off for a particular scenario - there is nothing like best for all situations.

Hope it helps !!